# XPages: callback not working inside a dynamicContent control

Tags: xpages, custom-controls

Can someone please explain why the following XPage isn't working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xc:ccLoadDelayed>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:div xp:key="content">content</xp:div>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xc:ccLoadDelayed>
</xp:view>
```

where ccLoadDelayed is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xe:dynamicContent id="ccLoadDelayed">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="element" disableOutputTag="true">
                element
                <xp:callback facetName="content"></xp:callback>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="ccLoadDelayed" immediate="true">
        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("ccLoadDelayed").show("element")}]]></xe:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

What I see (in a browser) is the word *element*, but the word *content* doesn't appear, so apparently the *callback* doesn't work. Why oh why? And how can I make it work? Thanks for your help!

** MORE INFO **

If I put this code in ccLoadDelayed, both words are displayed correctly, but there is no partial update, which is the whole purpose of this exercise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:div>
        element
        <xp:callback facetName="content"></xp:callback>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

And just for completeness' sake, the single XPage that works (without a callback):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xe:dynamicContent id="ccLoadDelayed">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="element" disableOutputTag="true">
                element
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="ccLoadDelayed" immediate="true">
        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("ccLoadDelayed").show("element")}]]></xe:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your dynamicControl is missing the property "defaultFacet". If you don't provide a default facet the dynamicControl display nothing and you have to display the corresponding facet programmaticly.

dynamicControls are used to display an arbitrary number of facets. Which facet is displayed can be controlled programmaticly.

Take a look at this [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/user/extlib_controls_dynamic.html) how dynamicControls are supposed to work.

Comment: When I put everything in the XPage itself, it works, even without the default Facet. The onClientLoad event code does its job: it changes to the element facet. So it is not correct that nothing is displayed when the page is opened: the word 'element' is shown, however I would also like to see the word 'content' from the XPage.

Comment: When everything is on the xpage do you have an editableArea within the dynamicContent and your div has a xp:key property? I would suppose that an editable area within a dynamicContent simply doesn't work.

Comment: Of course not: if everything is on one XPage, there is no need for an editable area. There is only the dynamic Content element, without the defaultFacet, because the facet is set later using the onClientLoad event. I also assume that these controls are not supposed to be used together, but I'd like to know for sure. My ccLoadDelayed could be very useful!